# How to display cross symbol as superscript with unicode?

Tags: iphone, unicode

I want to display a cross in the place of superscript, I know the unicode character of the cross (\u2020).

Answer (score 2):

Unicode encodes plain text. Superscripting isn’t plain text, so you need something external to, or “on top of” plain text. For example, on a web page, you could use the CSS to position character above the baseline (and reduce font size). In a word processor, you would use superscripting command or style.

In Unicode, there is a limited number of superscript characters, i.e. variants of characters in superscript style encoded as separate characters, such as superscript two “²”. But Unicode has no mechanism for superscripts in general.